# How to transfer batches of data from one database to the other database of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now thinking if I can set up a temporary Apache IoTDB database to transfer large amount of data. May I ask how to import data from one IoTDB server to another IoTDB server in batches (such as the data of a database)? I currently use Version 1.2 of Apache IoTDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data synchronization function of Apache IoTDB V1.2.0 can transfer large amount of data by exporting CSV files or exporting TsFiles and then importing them to another instance. You can then copy the TsFiles to another instance and load it with the `load` command.